# Recorded video Can't read from the file Location Instantly?

Tags: android, mediastore, video-recording, android-external-storage, file-read

I am Recording a video using my android application.when i am trying to read the video from the path after recording i did'nt get the full recorded file.
but after some time i can read the full file.i don't know what is the problem?
please help.
Here is my code

try {
                videoFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
                videothumb = new File(getOutputMediaThumbFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO), videoFile.getName());
                db.insertFileInfo(videoFile.getName(), 0, videoFile.length(), 0, "video/mp4");
                if (videoFile == null) {
                    Log.d("", "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
                    safeToTakePicture = true;
                    return null;
                }

```
            videothumb.createNewFile();
            videoFile.createNewFile();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            upVFile = new File(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
            FileOutputStream ftos = new FileOutputStream(videothumb);
            thumb = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmv, 200, 200, false);
            thumb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, ftos);
            ftos.flush();
            ftos.close();
            bmv.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmv.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
            String encodedImage = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(b));
            editor.putString("image_data", encodedImage);
            editor.commit();
            editor.putString(IMAGE_NAME, videoFile.getName());
            editor.commit();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*write a method for refreshing gallery*

```
private void refreshGallery(File file){

Intent mediaScanIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);

mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));

sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

}
```